# .net 6.0 Compatibility issue with nuget packages

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, nuget, .net-6.0

I upgraded my projects from .Net Core 3.1 to .Net 6, and updated all of my Nuget packages, and now my Azure Timer functions no longer work.

I'm trying to run locally from Visual Studio, and I get the below runtime error (see image).  Image also shows all of my nuget packages.

[image]

Comment: my guess is that you're being affected by this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5894

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the project file, we need to update the Azure Functions version from v3 to v4.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The properties page doesn't have a setting for this.  This needs to be done directly in the project file.

Comment: after some discussion, we agree that this needs to be a project level setting.